# 'All grown up and doing the town'?

Tags: meaning, expressions

Can any native English speaker and movie fan inform me about this expression:
"**all grown up and doing the town**"?

I found this expression in "**Goodfellas**" movie but I didn't understand its real meaning.

Thanks in advance

Comment: As far as I am aware (try Googling it) 'doing the town' means being a tourist and seeing the sites in an efficient manner. You might need more context to generate interest.

Comment: "Doing the town" can mean simply being a tourist, or it can mean visiting various rowdy venues (bars, dance halls, brothels, etc).  Depends on context.

Answer (score 1):

*doing the town* is an idiom that means going to lots of fun places in the city like bars and nightclubs. These generally only admit adults, and *all grown up* means having become an adult, so the people discussed are able to do the town.